# How do you automatically produce documentation from JSDoc in SvelteKit?

Tags: sveltekit, jsdoc

I've googled all the possible permutations of this question but I can't find anything about it. There is very little information on how to use JSDoc in SvelteKit and nothing really about how to configure it or produce documentation from JSDoc, which is actually one of it's main features.
I'm starting a new project and want to use only JSDoc for type safety but I would also like to get all the other benefits.
Has anyone got a clue?